# Generic class that can take any numbers OR anything else that can be added

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Title must be confusing, let me explain: Im writing a polynomial and so far it only works with double coefficients.

My idea is to make this class a generic one, where the user can specify the type of the coefficients, for example `Polynomial<Double>`. Now the coefficients cant be objects from any class, as they must have addition, subtraction, ... methods.

To solve this I made an Arithmetic interface with the necessary methods (add, subtract, multiply, divide) and now its `Polynomial<? extends Arithmetic>`.

But since Double does not implement this interface, of course, the user cant use Polynomial anymore.

My question in the end is: How can I make Polynomial generic in a way that the user can pass a subclass of java.lang.Number (or at least Double) OR my Arithmetic interface? If it cant be done, what should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand, but rather than have `Polynomial` implement `Arithmetic`, can't it just implement `Number`?

Comment: I wrote this on mobile and apperantly the "less, greater" symbols and everything inside them disappeared... sorry about that, dont know why is it so.

Comment: It's interpreted as HTML. Fixed it for you

Comment: Okey so suppose I make Polynomial implement Number (which is weird, because its not a number, only its coefficients are). How will the user then be able to use their own classes (which implement Aritmetic) as coefficients then? To clarify I dont want Polynomial to implement Arithmetic either, its for the possible coefficient classes.

Comment: Well, the problem is that `Number` doesn't provide methods for calculations so in order to use those you'd need to provide a wrapper anyways. If it is possible with your requirements you could provide a generic wrapper class like `NumberArithmetic<T extends Number> implements Arithmetic` that can be passed to `Polynomial<T extends Arithmetic>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to define a `Polynomial<T>` *interface* that has no restrictions on `T` whatsoever.

Then do an implementation of `ArithmeticPolynomial implements Polynomial<Arithmetic>`.

Then you can do another implementation for `Number` types, which just re-uses `ArithmeticPolynomial`, like this: `NumberPolynomial<T extends Number> implements Polynomial<T>`. This will use a wrapper/adapter class `NumberArithmetic`. Which wraps (adapts) a `Number` to `Arithmetic`.

If I understood you correctly, that would do it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the NumberArithmetic class? As far as I know you can ready do arithmetics with Integer, Double, ... (well, on their primitives, using the +,*,-,/ operators). What kind of tasks would this class do?

Comment: You would want to reuse the `ArithmeticPolynomial` implementation. To  re-use that, you need an `Arithmetic` implementation. Since `Double` for example doesn't implement that, you have to implement it. It would do nothing, just delegate calls from `Arithmetic.add` to `Double.sum` or whatever. The class would not be visible to the user, it would only be used inside `NumberPolynomial`. Does that help?

Comment: I beleive it does, thank you! So in the end the answer to my question is to disassemble the Polynomial class into multiple interfaces and classes.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this using a recursive datastructure.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Polynomial {

private static class Term{
    Object coefficient;
    Object base;
    Object power;

    Term(Variable v){
        this.coefficient = 1;
        this.base = v;
        this.power = 1;
    }

    Term(Number n){
        this.coefficient = 1;
        this.base = n;
        this.power = 1;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String tmp = "";
        if(coefficient instanceof Number){
            double c = ((Number) coefficient).doubleValue();
            if(c != 1.0)
                tmp += ((Number) coefficient).doubleValue();
        }
        if(coefficient instanceof Polynomial){ tmp += "(" + coefficient.toString() + ")";}

        if(!tmp.isEmpty())
            tmp += "•";

        if(base instanceof  Number){ tmp += ((Number) base).doubleValue(); }
        if(base instanceof Variable){tmp += base.toString(); }

        if(power instanceof Number){
            double p = ((Number) power).doubleValue();
            if(p != 1.0)
                tmp += ((Number) power).doubleValue();
        }
        if(power instanceof Polynomial){tmp += base.toString(); }

        // return
        return tmp;
    }
}

private List<Term> terms = new ArrayList<>();

public Polynomial add(Variable variable){
    if(terms.isEmpty()){
        terms.add(new Term(variable));
        return this;
    }
    // search for same variable
    for(Term t : terms){
        if(t.base.equals(variable)){
            addToCoefficient(t);
            return this;
        }
    }
    // similar term not found
    terms.add(new Term(variable));
    return this;
}

public Polynomial add(Number number){
    if(terms.isEmpty()){
        terms.add(new Term(number));
        return this;
    }
    // search for any number
    for(Term t : terms){
        if(t.base instanceof Number){
            t.base = ((Number) t.base).doubleValue() + number.doubleValue();
            return this;
        }
    }
    // default
    return this;
}

private void addToCoefficient(Term t){
    if(t.coefficient instanceof Number){ t.coefficient = ((Number) t.coefficient).doubleValue() + 1.0; }
    if(t.coefficient instanceof Polynomial){ t.coefficient = ((Polynomial) t.coefficient).add(1); }
}

public String toString(){
    String tmpA = "";
    String tmpB = "";
    for(Term t : terms) {
        tmpA = t.toString();
        tmpB += (tmpA.startsWith("+") || tmpB.startsWith("-")) ? tmpA : ("+" + tmpA);
    }
    return tmpB;
}
```

}

This class essentially stores a polynomial as a list of terms.

Whenever an operation is needed (e.g. addition) the polynomial class decides:

- do I need to create a separate term for this
- or do I need to delegate arithmetic to an existing term

Creating a separate term is the trivial case

Delegating to an existing term will typically imply some kind of operation either on the power of that term, or the coefficient.

Either these are numbers (in which case easy peasy) or they are polynomials, and you simply recurse into the datastructure.

The code I provided can be called like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Polynomial p = new Polynomial();
    p.add(3)
            .add(10)
            .add(new Variable("a"))
            .add(new Variable("a"));

    System.out.println(p);
}
```

Which outputs:

> +13.0+2.0•a

Comment: It is definiately an interesting concept, but the problem is that my polynomial is kind of "irreducible", and since all of it already written in that way I would have to completely re-write everything, whereas with with the generics soulution I merely need to replace the + ooerator with an add method, and so on. But thank you for the detailed answer, if I have to re-think my class completely I will definiately use some if these concepts.

Comment: I think ultimately you may need to move to this concept if you go beyond the simple use-case.
And it shouldn't be a re-write if you have ensured other things only interact with Polynomial through an interface.